# Why do I have -1 rep on a downvote after hitting the rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I apparently hit the rep cap today since the last up vote only gave me +1 rep. Still, after making a down vote my rep is reduced by 1. I was expecting it to show no reputation change. Am I missing something?

Comment: You mean that you expect to have a sort of "surplus" of 9 rep that should be able to absorb negative rep changes?

Comment: @Josh: yes, exactly. Just like any upvotes show no reputation change after reaching the cap.

Comment: Sounds fair to me. You only get 1 rep due to the cap, those extra 9 never exist. Any subsequent rep-reducing action you take later subtracts as usual.

Comment: @CubeJockey: I think it depends on how you look at it. To me it would be fair to have the mentioned 'surplus', equal to the amount of 'lost' reputation in the given day.

Comment: While it sounds like Eugene is being selfish about having extra rep, it sort of makes sense. Had he made the downvote before he got an upvote, he would have gotten +2 rep and then still hit the rep cap. Why should it matter which happened first, if they were on the same day?

Comment: @McAdam331: Not saying it's right or wrong, but it's also consistent with what happens on the other end. If you post an answer at rep 1, then get 3 downvotes followed by an upvote, you wind up with more rep than if you had gotten the upvote first followed by 3 downvotes.

Comment: @JohnY that's a really good point.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The rep cap is not applied to the sum of all transactions that take place in that day, but rather on every individual transaction.  Any time you would gain rep, any rep that would put you beyond the rep cap is lost, forever, at that instant.

Comment: @pnuts When votes are undone, possibly through the deletion of a post, the way it resolves such removals is to essentially answer the question of, "what would your rep had been if this action had never happened in the first place?" So if an upvote is lost due to a deleted post/user, it's possible to have no effect on your rep, if you still end up hitting the rep cap when viewing the world as if that post/user had never existed.  Note that this doesn't result in you *gaining* rep, it just results in you not losing it.

Comment: Is it really lost *forever* ? I remember at least one [reputation recalc](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) on SO.

Comment: @eugeney a rep recalc is just correcting for errors in the computation of the rep total.  If the system hadn't made an error in the first place, there would be no rep changed.  Keep in mind that all of the root information from which the reputation is derived is still kept, which is why you can recalculate rep in the first place.

Comment: @pnuts That is correct.

Comment: There's also the oddity that order will have an effect.  I.E. if you get all your upvotes to max out your rep, and then one downvote, you'll get -1 applied.  You get a downvote and then all your upvotes you get the max.  Why should the order have affect the total if the number of ups and downs are the same?  By design or not, it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I'd just be happy to have received so many _meaningless internet points_ that they stopped counting...

Comment: @RobBaillie It's not a bug, it's by design.  You may not like the design, but that doesn't make it a bug.  If you pour 2 cups of water into a 1 cup container, and then pour out half a cup, would you expect the container to still be full because you poured 2 cups in and only took 1/2 cup out?  Would you thing that the order doesn't matter when adding/removing water into the container?

Comment: Something to remember is that this works both for gaining rep and losing rep. For example if a new user makes a posts and gets a couple of down votes and later an up vote they will not lose any rep from the previous down votes even though they now have rep they can lose.

Comment: @Servy Using an analogy to prove a point of functional design misses an important point, I.E. you can come up with an analogy to prove *any* point.  How about instead taking the design to the extreme?  I post an answer that gets 5000 up votes, then 200 down votes.  Presumably I get zero for the day.  If I get 200 downs and *then* 5000 ups I get 200.  That doesn't feel like it's right.  As I said in my earlier post, I *get* that's the design, I just suspect it's a technical design that has led to a functional oddity that has been accepted rather than a true functional design decision.

Comment: @RobBaillie This isn't some new discovery that nobody has noticed before.  This has been brought up many times.  SE has made it clear that this is the intended design.  If you want to propose a change to the design, then feel free to write a proposal, and explain why the benefits of making the change that you want would merit the time spent and any negative consequences.

Answer (score 3):

Just like when you post answer when starting out, and you get down-voted, then you post a better question, and it gets up-voted, then you have 6 rep.

---

Here's a list of the events and the order in which they happen in (from my example above):

1. You make an SO account.
2. You ask a bad question.
3. Your question is down-voted.
4. You "lose" 2 Rep.
5. But your Rep is still at 1.
6. You learn from your mistakes.
7. You ask a better question.
8. It gets up-voted.
9. You now have 6 Rep.
10. And so on.

---

As you can see, if you would add up Rep at the end of that day, you would have 4 Rep (1 - 2 + 5 = 4), but you have 6 because SO's system adds it up as you go and doesn't ever go negative (1).

I know this wasn't exactly what you where asking, but I think it draws a very good analogy, and I felt this needed to be added.

Hope this helped!

---

References:

(1)

> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1.

Found Here: [stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)